# ImageMagick Needs a Dependency That Doesn't Exist?

Tags: imagemagick, rpm

In attempting to install the latest ImageMagick (and devel) RPM from http://www.imagemagick.org/download/linux/CentOS/x86_64/ I receive this message

```
ImageMagick-libs = 6.8.5-8 is needed by ImageMagick-devel-6.8.5-8.x86_64
```

Confusingly, there is no ImageMagick-libs RPM listed, and searching has yet to yield a solution. Is there a way around this existential dependency?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither I nor Google know where ImageMagick-libs lives nor what it contains, but for posterity  this gets things up and running on CentOS 5.8 (the distribution listed on imagemagick.org):

```
>: rpm -Uvh --nodeps ImageMagick-6.8.5-8.x86_64.rpm ImageMagick-devel-6.8.5-8.x86_64.rpm
>: ln -s /usr/include/ImageMagick-6 /usr/include/ImageMagick
```

The symbolic link was necessary for software relying on ImageMagick header files.

Comment: You should mark your own answer as being the correct one so that this doesn't show up under unanswered.

Comment: I've needed it for install ImageMagick-devel and with the --nodeps it was successfully installed and I was able to install from pecl the imagick extension as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If someone were to stumble upon this, the ImageMagick-libs RPM are now downloadable from the [link in the question](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/linux/CentOS/x86_64/).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing when building the RPMs myself.

line 66 of the SRPM's included ImageMagick spec file includes:

```
Requires: %{name}-libs = %{version}-%{release}
```

I just commented out that line and the build completes; the resultant RPM satisfies the requirement cleaner. In sum, I believe it a bug in the SPEC file bundled in the SRPM. It isn't necessary for functionality even when building against php magickwand and similar finicky tools that require headers from ImageMagick.